# Get Config Path value based on website scope

Tags: magento2, cms, system-config

From a CMS Page, block or transactional email it's possible to get a config path value for the website url with:

```
{{config path="general/store_information/country_id"}}
```

Is it possible to get this value for a specific website scope, say I have to websites in our magento installation, one for the Netherlands and the other for the UK.  Is it possible to get the UK value here from the Netherlands website with something like...

```
{{config path="web/unsecure/base_url" website="2"}}
```

Comment: I think if you use store rather than website that may work.

Comment: @PeterO'Callaghan, didn't work.  I tried it using both the store id & code.  thanks anyway

Comment: Just looking at M1, I don't think it's possible to get a config value from another store. Given the example in your question, in M1 I believe `{{store _store="2"}}`, hopefully it'll transfer over to M2.